# How to fix SQL error "A symbol name was expected"

Tags: sql, mysql, constraints

I am currently working on a database in phpmyadmin. I am trying to add a constraint in my customer table, to ensure that any phone number entered must start with a 0, followed by 10 or 11 digits.

My problem arises when I try to add a constraint. This is what I have tried (I added this line with the creation of my table, after adding my unique keys. (see below) ) :

```
CONSTRAINT `cust_pnum_check`
CHECK(`Phone_Number` REGEX '^0\d{10}|\d{11}$')
```

When I enter this, the `CHECK` is underlined with a message saying **"A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword cannot be used as a column name without backquotes (near CHECK)"**.
I understand that this would usually happen when trying to use a reserved keyword as a column name without enclosing it in backquotes, but I'm not sure where i have done that here.

for reference, here is the customer table:

(EDIT: I have now included the constraint line that caused the error here too, so this is now the full code that resulted in the error: )

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
`Customer_ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`First_Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`Last_Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`Contact_Email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`Phone_Number` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`Home_Address` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`Postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Cust_Username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`Cust_Password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(`Customer_ID`),

UNIQUE KEY `Contact_Email` (`Contact_Email`),
UNIQUE KEY `Cust_username` (`Cust_Username`),

CONSTRAINT `cust_pnum_check` CHECK(`Phone_Number` REGEX '^0\d{10}|\d{11}$')

)
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: I asked my tutor about this today and he said that such an operation could not be performed in phpmyadmin?** I am unsure if this is true but for now I think I will do my data validations in php instead of sql. I'll still leave this post up just in case there is an actual solution to this issue though.

Comment: Did you remember to add a comma at the end of the previous line?

Comment: Please show the full code that got the error.

Comment: Phone numbers do have extensions, so this might be a huge assumption that proves to be problematic.

Comment: @Barmar yes i added the comma, and I have added the full code that got the error, I just broke it up a bit. I'll edit the post now to show the full code

Comment: @tadman This is true! However this is only for a project, we have been told to  work with the assumption that all phone numbers start with 0.

Comment: I pasted your code into db-fiddle.com, the error message is different. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aJSFJdRnHXwwHKqnULLUoa/0 So I think you've copied the code incorrectly.

Comment: I posted an answer about your use of `REGEX` being a mistake. The MySQL operator is spelled `REGEXP`. But this is not related to the error message you describe above.

Comment: @BillKarwin i saw that answer, and it was useful nonetheless! thanks again.